# Javascript Iframe DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe

Trying to put this code:

```
var i = 0;
document.onmousemove = (function bbb() {
    if (i < 1) {
        i++;
        a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        st = 'iframe';
        r = st;
        b = document.createElement(r);
        b.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le' + '.com';
        b.width = 300;
        b.height = 300;
        b.marginHeight = 10;
        b.marginWidth = 10;
        b.frameborder = 10;
        b.align = 'left';
        a.appendChild(b);
    } else {
        return;
    }
})
```

works fine, but why do not work multiple

```
var i = 0;
document.onmousemove = (function bbb() {
    if (i < 1) {
        i++;
        a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        st = 'iframe';
        r = st;
        b = document.createElement(r);
        b.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le' + '.com';
        b.width = 300;
        b.height = 300;
        b.marginHeight = 10;
        b.marginWidth = 10;
        b.frameborder = 10;
        b.align = 'left';
        a.appendChild(b);
    } else {
        return;
    }
})


var i2 = 0;
document.onmousemove = (function bbbb() {
   if (i2 < 1) {
       i2++;
       a2 = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       st2 = 'iframe';
       r2 = st2;
       b2 = document.createElement(r2);
       b2.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le2' + '.com';
       b2.width = 300;
       b2.height = 300;
       b2.marginHeight = 10;
       b2.marginWidth = 10;
       b2.frameborder = 10;
       b2.align = 'right';
       a2.appendChild(b2);
   } else {
       return;
   }
})
```

does not work??? How to run multiple frames?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Do you get error messages? What did you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, whitespace would be nice.

But it looks like your problem is you are setting the body.onmousemove twice... so the second time you set it your first one would be overwritten. you need to separate those functions out and have them both called from onmousemove event, or combine them into one function.

**Separate them out:**

```
    document.onmousemove=(function() { bbb(); bbbb(); });

function bbb() {
    var i=0;
    if (i < 1) {
        i++;
        a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        st = 'iframe';
        r = st;
        b = document.createElement(r);
        b.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le' + '.com';
        b.width = 300;
        b.height = 300;
        b.marginHeight = 10;
        b.marginWidth = 10;
        b.frameborder = 10;
        b.align = 'left';
        a.appendChild(b);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function bbbb() {
   var i2=0;
   if (i2 < 1) {
       i2++;
       a2 = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       st2 = 'iframe';
       r2 = st2;
       b2 = document.createElement(r2);
       b2.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le2' + '.com';
       b2.width = 300;
       b2.height = 300;
       b2.marginHeight = 10;
       b2.marginWidth = 10;
       b2.frameborder = 10;
       b2.align = 'right';
       a2.appendChild(b2);
   } else {
       return;
   }
}
```

**Combine Them:**

```
document.onmousemove=(function() {

    var i=0;
    var i2=0;

    if (i < 1) {
        i++;
        a = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        st = 'iframe';
        r = st;
        b = document.createElement(r);
        b.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le' + '.com';
        b.width = 300;
        b.height = 300;
        b.marginHeight = 10;
        b.marginWidth = 10;
        b.frameborder = 10;
        b.align = 'left';
        a.appendChild(b);
    } else {
        return;
    }


   if (i2 < 1) {
       i2++;
       a2 = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       st2 = 'iframe';
       r2 = st2;
       b2 = document.createElement(r2);
       b2.src = 'h' + 't' + 'tp' + ':/' + '/examp' + 'le2' + '.com';
       b2.width = 300;
       b2.height = 300;
       b2.marginHeight = 10;
       b2.marginWidth = 10;
       b2.frameborder = 10;
       b2.align = 'right';
       a2.appendChild(b2);
   } else {
       return;
   }

});
```

Comment: This one works but not right, it looping functions, i need run function only once? so for me works with moving var i outside of function/ Thanks

Comment: the onmousemove event gets called each time the mouse moves... so setting this function to it would call the function... each time the mouse moved....
you will need to explain where and when you need this code to execute

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the `onmousemove` event handler of `document`.
To add multiple event handlers and not just one, you have to use the `addEventListener` function.

The other possibility would be to include all the code of the second handler in the first handler, so you still have only one handler.